# Show that $\nabla(fg)=f\nabla g+g\nabla f$

Tags: calculus, vectors, gradient-flows

This looks very much like the product rule to me. However, is this technically a valid answer to the question? How is it best answered?

Comment: If everything else fails, write each side out in coordinates, and use the plain old product rule for each component separately.

Comment: You can find a proof everywhere, and I'm sure that this had been asked here before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's definitely the product rule here. Since $\nabla = \left<\partial/\partial x,\ \  \partial/\partial y,\ \  \partial/\partial z\right>$,

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla(fg) &= \left<\frac{\partial}{\partial x} fg,\ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}fg,\ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}fg\right>&\mathrm{(Definition)}\\
&=\left<g\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f + f\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g,\ \ g\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f + f\frac{\partial}{\partial y} g,\ \ g\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f + f\frac{\partial}{\partial z} g\right> & \mathrm{(Product\ Rule)}\\
&= g \left<\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f,\ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f,\ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}f\right> + f \left<\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g,\ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}g,\ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}g\right>&\mathrm{(Grouping)}\\
&=g\nabla{}f + f\nabla{}g &\mathrm{(Definition)}
\end{align}
$$

So to answer your question, this is  a direct result of the product rule. As for "product rule" being a valid answer to the question, it depends on the context. While that answer would be correct, it definitely doesn't hurt to mathematically show *why* it's correct. And the best way to do that is break the $\nabla$ operator into it's components.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a product rule. And you write in coordinates it is as many product rules as coordinates

Comment: This sounds like a comment...

Comment: Sorry it is hint. May be a comment rather than an answer